# ASP.NET MVC Html Helper usage

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, html, model-view-controller

Could anyone guide me how to use MVC html helper to implement to get the same html output below . I am a junior MVC developer trying to learn the stuff.

```
<ul class="nav fl mrgtp7m nodisp-ie7"> 
    <li class="prdctType">
      <a class="selected" id="A1">Infy Plus®</a> 
      <ul class="subnav" id="Ul1"><li><a>Infy Test Plus®       
       </a></li><li><a>Infy® Test General</a></li></ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Tried it with HTML dropdown helper but did not get same result.Not sure how can i apply above CSS classes in helper class to achive the same above

```
 <ul class='nav fl mrgtp7m nodisp-ie7'> 
         <li class='prdctType'>
                @Html.DropDownListFor("Test", new SelectList(listItems , "Value" , "Text") )
          </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an HTML Helper?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor` generates a `<select>` tag, not a `<ul>` tag. Since this appears to be static data, why do you need a helper?

Comment: If you want to do this with a custom HtmlHelper I'd start by looking at the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/Html/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs) for ideas. You will probably be using [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) and [TagBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx) to construct your markup.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Add the class in your `ul` or in your `DropDownListFor`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any helper classes for this. Use foreach with your model based on the logic that need to implement.